# Kendo UI Grid Inserts/Updates create Duplicate Records (again)

Tags: json, kendo-ui, duplicates, kendo-grid

I have same problem as Daniel had in this topic, but his solution doesn't work for me:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/kendo-ui-grid-inserts-updates-create-duplicate-records.aspx#-jhxqRrNAUGsTFJaC-Ojwg

So use-case. Users adds 2 new records one after another:

1. Presses "Add new record" button of a grid
2. Fills the fields (name="Alex", amount=10, comment="first").
3. Record one is ready. Press 'Save'. (data goes to controller and than to Database)
4. User see one record in a grid
5. Press "Add new record" button again
6. Fills fields (name="Bob", amount=20, comment = "second").
7. Record one is ready. Press 'Save'. Data goes to controller and than to Database.
   In this moment something happens and grid send Ajax request again with record one data to controller.
8. User updates grid and see three records

   "Alex | 10  |  first" (duplicated record)  ID = 1

   "Bob  | 20  |  second"  ID = 2

   "Alex | 10  |  first"   ID = 1

They recommend to return an ID for correct binding\update of data source with new record.
And I return it (new ID from database comes in response with bouns entity)! and this doesn't help.
Only if I add first record and refresh page with F5 and after that add second record everything is ok. But if add another one, the third records - problems appears again

Code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(BonusDto bonusDto)
    {
        BonusAggregate bonus;

        if (bonusDto.Amount <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Amount should be more than 0");

        if (bonusDto.EmployeeId <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("You should specify an existing employee");

        using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            BonusesRepository = new BonusesRepository(dbContext);
            var employeeRepository = new EmployeesRepository(dbContext);
            bonus = new BonusFactory(employeeRepository).Create(bonusDto);

            BonusesRepository.Save(bonus);
        }

        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
        return Json(bonus); // try to return ID after bonus was saved
    }
```

UI Code

```
// creates bonuses grid control
$("#bonusesGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: bonusesDataSource,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    editable: "inline",
    columns: [
        "BonusId",
        "EmployeeId",
        {
            field: "EmployeeLastName",
            editor: employeeAutocompletingEditor,
            template: "#=EmployeeLastName#"
        },
        "Amount",
        {
            field: "Comment",
            titel: "Comment",
            editor: textareaEditor,
            filterable: {
                operators: {
                    number: {
                        contains: "Contains"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            command: ["edit"],
            title: " "
        }
    ],
    save: function(e) {
        if (newValueEmployeeId !== undefined && 
                            newValueEmployeeLastName !== undefined && 
                            newValueEmployeeLastName !== "") {
                              setNewValueEmployeeIdAndLastName(newValueEmployeeId, newValueEmployeeLastName);
                              gridDataSource.model.EmployeeId = newValueEmployeeId; // it's a hack to bind model and autocomplete control
                              gridDataSource.model.EmployeeLastName = newValueEmployeeLastName;
                        } else {
                              gridDataSource.model.EmployeeId = currentValueEmployeeId;
                              gridDataSource.model.EmployeeLastName = currentValueEmployeeLastName;

                        }
    },
    edit: function(e) {
        setCurrentValueEmployeeIdAndLastName(e.model.EmployeeId, e.model.EmployeeLastName);
    },
    cancel: function(e) {
        setCurrentValueEmployeeIdAndLastName(e.model.EmployeeId, e.model.EmployeeLastName);
    }
});
```

Bonus data source:

```
// bind json result from /Bonuses/GetPagedJsonBonuses
        var bonusesDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {

                    read: {
                         url: "@Url.Action("GetPagedJsonBonuses", "Bonuses")",
                         type : "GET",
                         contentType: "application/json",
                         dataType: "json",
                         cache: false
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Bonuses")",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                        if (operation === "update" || operation === "create") {

                            // correct format for conversion 
                            var d = new Date(options.Date);
                            options.Date = kendo.toString(d, dateFormat);

                            // updates the BonusDTO.EmployeeId with selected value
                            if (newValueEmployeeId !== undefined)
                                options.EmployeeId = newValueEmployeeId;
                        }
                        if(operation === "read") {
                            options.filter = setFormattedFilterDate(options.filter);
                        }
                        return options;
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 15,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                error: showErrorMessage,
                schema: {
                    data: "Data", // PagedResponse.Data
                    total: "TotalCount", // PagedResponse.TotalCount
                    model: {
                        id: "BonusId",  // Data
                        fields: {
                            EmployeeId: { type: "number" },
                            EmployeeLastName: {
                                type: "string",
                                editable: true,
                                nulable: false,
                                validation: { required: {message: "Employee's last name is required"}}
                            },
                            Date: {
                                type: "date",
                                editable: true,
                                nullable: false,
                                validation: {
                                    required: { message: "Date is required to be set" }
                                }
                            },
                            Amount: {
                                type: "number",
                                editable: true,
                                nullable: false,
                                defaultValue: 1,
                                validation: {
                                    required: { message: "Amount is required to be set" }
                                }
                            },
                            Comment: { type: "string", editable: true }
                        } // fields
                    } // model
                }// schema 
            });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't seen this problem in my code.  I do however have a "complete" event handler on my create and update events that refreshed the grid - it may help you:

```
  dataSource: {

    type: "jsonp",
    transport: {
        read: UrlBase + "getAll",
        update: {
            url: UrlBase + "Update",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            complete: function (e) {
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

            }
        },
        create: {
            url: UrlBase + "create",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            complete: function (e) {
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            }
        },
        destroy: {
            url: UrlBase + "destroy",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            complete: function (e) {
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            }
        }
    },
   ...
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. Is '#grid' an element name of a grid? and what is kendoGrid in data("kendoGrid") ???

Comment: It's the element id of the grid.  `<div id="grid" style="width: 960px">`.  The kendoGrid etc. are internal KendoGrid values so they will work for you.

Comment: thanks again. It works. But I explored documentation and found no inforamtion about event "complete". How did you find it?

Comment: I wen't back to look and i can't find it either!  it must of either been in the older docs or an answer on SO somewhere.  The closest info i could find was on a Kendo forum - but not the same events.  http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/datasource-success-event.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Yes, hamed is correct.  Your "create" action result passes in the object from your model that is to be saved to your database.  Have the INSERT in your data access layer return the newly created key ("ID") in the database.  Use this key to now set the "ID" field on your model that's passed in to the action result and then passed back to the view as JSON.  Now the grid should know it's just created this record and does not need to do anything more with it.  Otherwise, the model object returns with the "ID" field set to 0 so the grid thinks it still needs to add this record.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Grid_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, MyObject obj)
    {
        if (obj != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            obj.Id = _myService.Create(obj);
        }

        return Json(new[] { obj }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Comment: This answer is better. You do not need to have the grid read again just because you inserted - it will deal with that in the UI.

Comment: Yes you need to make sure that the id is set and is named the same as it is defined in your schema. See the important note in this link for details. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.create

Answer (score 3):

This error occur when you did not pass Primary key to view in read action.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Quinton Bernhardt's complete event: bind the dataSource.read() to the kendo sync event.

I'm using kendo's C# MVC's html helpers which don't expose the sync event, so I had to modify it after setting up the grid.

On window load:

```
var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.bind("sync", function () {
     $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
});
```

The sync event fires after the save request has been completed. The `dataSource.read()` gets the latest from the server, including the id that was set server side.

Comment: This worked for my non-hierarchical grids only. The hierarchical grids still duplicate inserts when user adds multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, did various trials but fixed with the following trial

**Jquery**

```
   create: {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "../../ajax/ajaxGv.aspx/addstaff"
            },

            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation == "create" && options.models) {  
                    return JSON.stringify({ "oStaff": options.models });
                }
```

**VB.Net**

```
   'Adding Staff
   <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Sub addStaff(ByVal oStaff As Object)
    Dim strJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oStaff)
    Dim lstStaff As List(Of Staff) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Staff))(strJson)
    Dim db As New LiveB2cDataContext
    Try

            db.Staff.InsertAllOnSubmit(lstStaff)
        Next
        db.SubmitChanges()

      'Fix is that you need to return the objects you have added in the database back as json to kendo

        strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstStaff, Formatting.None)
        WriteJson(strJson) ' Returning the objects added as json back to Kendo
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorLog(ex)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Shared Sub WriteJson(strJson As String)
    Try

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strJson)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorLog(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**`Fix is that you need to return the objects you have added in the database back as json to kendo`**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is part of your issue, but in your DataSource's schema model you specify that the ID is the field named "BonusId", but that field isn't specified in the array of fields.

Comment: do you mean this part of code:

 schema: {  model: {
                        id: "BonusId",  // THIS ONE?
                        fields: {
                            EmployeeId: { ...},
                           EmployeeLastName: {...}....


If so, that's correct. ID is not a part of the list of fields. ID  has to be specified directly in "model" area.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a simular issue.

I fixed it but making sure the id in the model is referring to a field:-

```
model: {
      id: "Id",
      fields: {
           Id: { editable: false, type: "number" },
           AnotherName: { editable: true, type: "string" },
           AnotherId: { editable: true, type: "number" }
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve the asker's problem, but hopefully might help someone with the same issue.

For us, this problem was being caused by errors being returned in JSON. Some required properties didn't have a value, but weren't related to the data we were displaying in the grid. Giving those properties a default value in the grid solved the issue.

You can view the JSON that's being returned by using [Fiddler Web Debugging Tools](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).